# processing single dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, initialization, swap

I'm trying to create an array with user input from a dialog box. It's supposed to ask how many numbers the user wants to enter, then ask the user to input the numbers. The code is then supposed to output the numbers in reverse order. Below is the code I have so far.. it doesn't work. I did something wrong with trying to initialize the array with user input. I'm pretty new to java so any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input;
    int space;
    double [] numbers;
    double count;
    String numberInput;
    double number;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            (null, "How many numbers would you like to enter?");
    space = Integer.parseInt(input);

    numbers = new double[space];

    count = 0;
    while (count < space)
    {
        numberInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null, "Enter a number to be sorted: ");
        number = Double.parseDouble(numberInput);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    numbers[i] = number;
        count++;
    }

   double[] numbers2 = swapArray(numbers);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numbers2);
}
public static double[] swapArray(double[] array)
{
    double[] result = new double[array.length];

    for (int i = 0, j = result.length - 1;
            i < array.length; i++, j--)
    {
        result[j] = array[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: I believe the brackets need to be next to the variable name. And have you tried using the index when putting the number into the array. That is definitely an issue but I can't be sure it is THE issue without the error report. Can you post it?

Comment: Have you considered iterating the array in reverse (instead of attempting to reverse the array)?

Comment: If you're new to Java, I suggest starting with the console instead of dialog or other more complex GUI; just to get the training and/or understanding of console-driven programs (including the very important **command-line parameters**, eventually).

Comment: CyberGeek.exe, which brackets and variable? I'll work on trying to initialize using the index somehow and see if that helps. I didn't get any errors when running this, only really weird end result messages such as "[D@4bf558aa"

Comment: Elliott Frisch, I could try iterating the array in reverse, I just wanted to try passing the array through the method because I think my professor wants us to know how. Do you think that's part of the problem?

Comment: TheLima, my professor has requested that we always use message dialog boxes instead of the console or I definitely would.. much easier to use input.nextDouble() in these cases!

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) numbers[i] = number;` doesn't make any sense. You're completely replacing the array's contents every time the `while` runs; I think you meant to use the `while`'s `count` instead of the for-loop with a `i`. Also, why are you using `double`s instead of `int`s? And why so much needless var-init clutter? I know you're a beginner, but you should get your habits right from the start, to avoid developing bad habits...Trust me; **I'm someone who developed bad habits...and regretted...A LOT**

Comment: Well, since the use of Dialog is part of your assignment, let me throw together my own console-based solution real quick...I think analyzing actual code in an answer will help you a lot faster than a thousand comments...and that way, you still have to roll your own version out, without copy-paste...should be a good compromise.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is actually my first time using arrays, so I definitely am still learning. Part of using so many doubles is from error messages about converting ints to doubles. I'll try working on that more and see if I can get them back to ints without the error messages. I think I've gotten to the point with this one that I just want it to work and if there's unnecessary code, I'm alright with it for now and will keep practicing similar projects to get better and making the code more organized and simple. My main problem is the initializing line with the while loop.

Comment: I'm going to do more research and probably try again almost from the beginning with this one, but I look forward to see what you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on your assignment. It should give you some ideas on how to deal with the problem, without giving you a copy-paste solution, nor the best-possible (to my own ability) structure/logic (but still giving you tips to point you in their direction):

```
package so_q33405148;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //TIP: You can use 'Scanner' instead of a 'Reader' here, to avoid having to parse strings into ints (scanner can do it for you)
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to enter?");
            int count = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int input[] = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter a number to be sorted: ");
                //TIP: With some clever math, you can invert the array right as it's still filling up here, by manipulating a new int (so 'i' is unchanged, as it's the for-loop's index) using 'i' and 'input.length'...Or, with a little creativity and insight, you may even achieve the same result manipulating 'i' directly somewhere else...
                input[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }

            System.out.println("Original array:\n" + Arrays.toString(input));

            //TIP: Better methods to reverse arrays and/or collections exist.
            //Take a look at SO question #3962766 (puritan solution without as much memory-footprint) and also Google about 'Arrays.asList()' and 'Collections.reverse()' (learn about collections-sorting)
            int reversedInput[] = new int[input.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                reversedInput[i] = input[count - i - 1];
            }

            System.out.println("Reversed array:\n" + Arrays.toString(reversedInput));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```